# Removing current version of app from download

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Need a help in critical issue with version released and currently ready for sale on appStore, we have found the issue, fixed and now decided to upload new version on appstore, while uploading  it provides a option with check box

> > Are you updating this app because of a significant usability issue or for a legal issue, such as infringement?

If we select yes, it shows all versions of app including current version of app with checkbox which is ready for sale

> > Select the box for each version of your app that cannot be enabled for iCloud download because of a significant usability issue or due to a legal issue such as infringement. Any versions you select will be unavailable for download as a previous purchase.

so i would like to know if we select current version of app which is ready for sale and upload new update, will the previous versions of app will be available for download.

Comment: I am not a specialist there, but if you want tour current version to "disappear", you should remove the app from all countries in the World. Since your app version is not a previous version, but the current one, you will not be able to disable that one until your new version is accepted. Then you'll be able to remove the current version from download for older devices.

Comment: @Injuanj thanks for reply, it's allowing to select current released version while uploading new, if we select yes checkbox for usability or legal issue, so need to know what will happen if I select yes and upload a new version

Answer (score 2):

**I decided to test this. Here are the results.**
First I want to clarify some of the confusion. There are two places where you can control the availability of previous versions of your app. If you go to `Rights and Pricing` in iTunesConnect and then scroll to the bottom and click `Manage iCloud download settings for this app`, you'll be able to select which versions of your app should **not** be available to users as a previous purchase. Notice that you cannot select the current version of your app.
[image: Rights and Pricing]
However, if you create a New Version of your app and then click "Prepare for Upload" you'll have the option to select Yes or No next to "Are you updating this app because of a significant usability issue or for a legal issue, such as infringement?" If you choose yes, the window will expand and you'll get a similar control where you can select versions that should not be available as a previous purchase. Except now, you **can** select the current version of your app. Although it doesn't make this clear, the *assumption* is that the current version of your app will only disappear from iCloud download availability **once** the new version is approved and live. I will test this.

As an aside, one of the reasons this feature was added (to download previous versions of an app) was so that users who's device or OS were too old for the current version could still download the latest version that their device/OS supports.

**What I Did**
So I decided to choose Yes and to select the current version to see what would happen (since there was a crashing bug in that version of my app). I don't expect this to remove my app from purchase availability since the verbiage seems to focus on iCloud download availability as a previous purchase.

My app has changed to `Waiting for Upload` and I can report that the current version is still available on the app store. Subsequently I uploaded and the status changed to Received and then `Waiting for Review`, and still my existing version is available.
I also decided to delete the app from my iPhone and then go to the App Store and tap the cloud button (which takes the place of the purchase button when you've previously purchased an app). It still allowed me to download the latest version (which is good).

I will keep this post updated with further developments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple have enabled a new feature, whereby older devices still have access to older versions of your app, you can select the older versions and make them unavailable though if you wish.

The feature is good for people with older devices, so they can still get your app if they are stuck on iOS 6 or whatever, but if you wish by checking the box beside each 'older' version you can ensure it's **not** available.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for reply, i want to know if i select the current version from list, will on appstore my app will rollback to previous version and peoples can download only previous version.

Answer (score 1):

"Any versions **you select** will be **unavailable** for download **as** a previous purchase." !

After you upload a new app, the currently ready for sale app will be one of the previous purchase! However, it might be not instantaneous and might be pending apple review for some time!

SO **IF** you **select** your **current** ready for sale **app** *then* it will **NOT** be **available** for *Download*!

In any case if you are not sure enought you can always send an email via iOS developer to apple and ask!

Comment: You mean to say that application will not be available for download completely or only current version will not be available for download, can users download previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers, Applied for expedited review and new version of app was approved within 8 hours and now its ready for sale. But sure I will contact apple ios developer center and get details of legal issue or significant usability issue checkbox.